# How to remove max-width in wordpress rss feed?

Tags: wordpress

This is the link to the rss feed: https://vom.com.au/feed/
There are 10 max-width in this file. But I couldn't find them anywhere on my site.

Is there anyway to remove max-width from rss feed?

Comment: Looks like you have added the inline styles while posting. Please check your post first. don't forget to check the content in text mode.

Comment: Thanks Kanu: I have checked the inline style, but there is nothing in there. This is the wield part. the max-width attributes are no where in the site, but only appears in RSS Feed.

Comment: anyone have solution for this?